# The "Stack Overflow for Teams" banner is not (fully) accessible

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams, accessibility

I have noticed that there is no way to close this banner using the keyboard alone. As you can see when you tab through it, the close button `X` is skipped:

[image]

The tabbing order is as follow:

1. Focus on *"add a comment"*
2. Next tab, focus on *"Learn more"*
3. Next tab, focus on *"Add Another Answer"*

The reason is because the close `X` "button" is not implemented with a `<button>` which would have naturally received focus.

[image]

Implementing synthetic buttons with `<div>` is ok but then it's better to:

1. Add a `tabindex="0"` to the `<div>`
2. Add a `role="button"` to the `<div>`

However that is not enough as as per [this recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/examples/button/button.html), hitting <kbd>SPACE</kbd> or <kbd>ENTER</kbd> should trigger the action (i.e. closing the banner). Some extra JavaScript is needed.

My recommendation would be to use a standard `<button>` element with an `onclick` handler. You should get both the focus and the native behaviour for free.

Also please note that the aria label is intended for screen readers, therefore "notice-dismiss" isn't ideal IMHO. `aria-label="dismiss this notice"` would make more sense I think. (Don't add an hyphen as some screen readers may actually spell it out.)

Comment: It's an ad for Teams, it's not _supposed_ to be easy to get rid of ;)

Comment: an ad that looks like one of teh usual "just in time" notifications. not cool

Comment: It's an ad, what are you thinking, StackOverflow wants you to look it for longer, the longer the better, of course, it's not in the list. ok, maybe its a bug...XD

Comment: I am also facing this issue. Can you suggest me how to get rid of this.

Comment: People should have equal opportunity to dismiss an ad though

Comment: Absolutely crucial; apparently there are some steps missing in SO protocols for adding UI elements. _"Is it accessible?"_ **must** be one of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for your report - this has been fixed and will be out with our next prod build. I basically followed your suggestion and used a standard `<button>` for dismissing the notice. Also updated `aria-label`.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick answer! I'm sure everybody here appreciate it. I certainly do.

Comment: gotta love bug reports that include clear recommendations on *how* to fix them <3